# Is W={P(x) | P(x) in P3 and P(0) = 1} a subspace of P3?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The question is as follows:

**Is W={P(x) | P(x) in P3 and P(0) = 1} a subspace of P3? If so find a basis and dimension.**

I am not sure how to answer this question in full.

So far I have the following work done for this question:

P(0) = 1

Any element of the vector space P3 is of the form:

a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3

Sub in x=1

a + b + c + d = 0

**Take any two vectors v and u to be:**

v = a1 + b1x + c1x^2 + d1x^3

u = a2 + b2x + c2x^2 + d2x^3

**Now check to see if they are closed under addition:**

r = v+u = (a1 + a2) + (b1 + b2)x + (c1 + c2)x^2 + (d1 + d2)x^3

r = a3 + b3x + c3x^2 + d3x^3

So its closed under addition?

**Now check to see if they are closed under scalar multiplication:**

c*v = cv = ca1 + cb1x + cc1x^2 + cd1x^3

c*u = cu = ca2 + cb2x + cc2x^2 + cd2x^3

So its closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: This is really hard to read. No MathJax and the double spacing means lots of unnecessary scrolling.

Comment: I dont know how to format it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: if $P(0)=1$ and $Q(0)=1$, what is $P(0)+Q(0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $W$ is not a subspace of $P_3$ since constantly zero polynomial $p(x) \equiv 0$ is not in it which a zero vector in $P_3$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $W$ is not a subspace of $P_3$. For instance, the constant polynomial $1$ belongs to $W$, but $1+1$ doesn't.

Comment: Could you explain this further?

Comment: The polynomial $1$ maps $0$ into $1$ and therefore $1\in W$, right?!. But if $W$ was a subspace, $1+1$ would have to belong to $W$. But it doesn't, since it maps $0$ into $2$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the polynomial 1 or when you say 1+1.

Comment: Isn't $P_3$ the space of the polynomials of the form $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3$? Isn't this equal to $1$ if $a=1$ and $b=c=d=0$?

Comment: So when I plug in x=0 I end up with a, which we are told equals 1.

Comment: Yes. But when we do that same thing with $2(=1+1)$, we get $2$. So, $2\notin W$.

Comment: Is the zero vector present here?